# Does the Mind Sliver cantrip's effect on saving throws stack with the Bane spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw, stacking

The cantrip [*mind sliver*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-sliver) from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (p. 108) has a secondary effect that subtracts 1d4 from the target's next saving throw:

> [...] subtract 1d4 from the next saving throw it makes before the end of your next turn.

The spell [*bane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bane) from the *Player's Handbook* (p. 216) has a similar effect:

> [...] the target must roll a d4 and subtract the number rolled from the attack roll or saving throw.

Does the saving throw penalty from *mind sliver* stack with the effect of *bane*, causing the target to subtract 2d4 from their next saving throw?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Yes it does.

The [rules for combining magical effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects) state:

> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap.

This rule goes on to impose stacking restrictions on separate castings of *the same spell*, but explicitly permits the effects of different spells to add together.

So if a creature finds itself under the effects of both *bane* and *mind sliver*, then they would subtract 2d4 from the next saving throw they make (before the end of the next turn of the caster of *mind sliver*).